# Apache behaving differently in localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ruby-on-rails

I have managed to install Apache2, Passenger and Ruby on Rails on a VPS machine with CentOS 5.5. To check everything is okay, I run in that machine `links http://localhost`, and the page is displayed correctly. This application is stored in `/var/www/webapp`.

However if I try to visit this page from outside. E.g.: `http://212.227.XYZ.ZZ`, I get the Apache welcome page located in `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/index.html`.

This is part of my `/etc/httpd/config/httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 212.227.XYZ.ZZ
   DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp/public
   <Directory /var/www/webapp/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have no idea why if I query the server from outside then I get different webpages. I have looked for config files in `/etc/httpd/conf/` but I haven't found any other config file but `httpd.conf`.

I have tried as well to put this webapp in `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/`, however I get the error: "Rails application failed to start properly".

How can I solve this problem? It's driving me crazy.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found the other config files which where overriding this behaviour. They are located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.